# SQL - Filter on another column when duplicate value is found in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have two tables a User Table and a Log table

The User Table has the following columns: id, name

The Log Table has the following columns: id, user_id(foreign key on User.id), last_updated_date, first_created_date. A user can have many logs, but the log of the user that is most important to us is the log that has the earliest first_created_date of that user.

Could someone help me formulate a query so that it returns a list of 100 ids of users that have have the earliest first_created_date for the logs that belong to that user?

Looking at the tables below, the user_ids that should be returned are 1 and 2. Since user_id 1 has the first earliest log which is Jan 1, 2019. Also since user_id 2 has the second earliest log (among the remaining users) which is Feb 1, 2019.

```
User Table
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | bob   |
+----+-------+
| 2  | carl  |
+----+-------+
| 3  | sandy |
+----+-------+



Log Table
+----+---------+-------------------+--------------------+
| id | user_id | last_updated_date | first_created_date |
+----+---------+-------------------+--------------------+
|  1 |       1 | not important     | Jan 1, 2019        |
|  2 |       1 | not important     | Jan 2, 2019        |
|  3 |       1 | not important     | Dec 3, 2019        |
|  4 |       2 | not important     | Feb 2, 2019        |
|  5 |       2 | not important     | Dec 3, 2019        |
|  6 |       3 | not important     | Mar 2, 2019        |
|  7 |       3 | not important     | Dec 3, 2019        | 
+----+---------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: I have updated it to just mysql. Thanks!

Comment: Store dates using a correct data type. And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate and use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select user_id
from log 
group by user_id
order by min(first_created_date)
limit 2  -- or limit 100?
```